# Enable textfield inside v-expansionpanel in vuetifyjs

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I am trying usecase where , text field should be disabled by default and 
it should be enabled only when that particular expansion panel content opens up

[image]

is this possible?
any suggestions would be helpful.

```
 <v-expansion-panel>
      <v-expansion-panel-content
        v-for="(item,i) in 5"
        :key="i"
      >
        <template v-slot:header>
           <v-flex xs6 pa-0 ma-0>
              <v-text-field style="backgroundColor:#3D8D7C" height="20px" 
                            placeholder="Edit text field"
                            class="pa-0 ma-0" >
               </v-text-field>
              </v-flex>
          <div>Panel {{i}}</div>
        </template>
        <v-card>
          <v-card-text>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</v-card-text>
        </v-card>
      </v-expansion-panel-content>
    </v-expansion-panel>
```

[This is what i have tried till now](https://codepen.io/adatdeltax/pen/abvXWQv?editors=1000)

Comment: Finally someone published a question with a reproduction link. Have an upvote, mate!

Comment: Thanks Alex, btw this https://codepen.io/adatdeltax/pen/XWmOgwa?editors=1011 can be  another  valid approach right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `v-model` to `<v-expansion-panels>` so you can track which panel is active. And then you can just check if the active panel index matches the text-field index.

Also add `@click.stop=""` to the fields to stop event propagation, otherwise, when you click on a field, the click would propagate through the field and close the panel. Though for some reason, if you click on the top part of a field it still closes the panel. That's a Vuetify bug.

You could fix it by wrapping the fields with a div that has `@click.stop=""` to stop click propagation through the whole text-field component. In the example below, I also specified a method: `@click.stop="handleFieldClick(index)"`. This way, when you click on the field, it will not only stop propagation but will also open the specified panel. Remove the method if you don't need this functionality.

### Demo

https://codepen.io/aQW5z9fe/pen/JjYxyxV?editors=1010

### Code

```html
<v-expansion-panels v-model="activePanel">
  <v-expansion-panel
    v-for="(item, index) in panels"
    :key="index"
  >
    <v-expansion-panel-header>
      Panel {{index}}
      <div @click.stop="handleFieldClick(index)"> 
        <v-text-field 
          @click.stop=""
          :ref="`field${index}`"
          :disabled="activePanel !== index"
          :label="activePanel !== index ? 'Disabled' : 'Type'"
          class="mx-4"
          filled dense hide-details 
        ></v-text-field>
      </div<
    </v-expansion-panel-header>
    <v-expansion-panel-content>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
    </v-expansion-panel-content>
  </v-expansion-panel>
</v-expansion-panels>
```

```js
methods: {
  handleFieldClick(index) {
    // Open specified panel
    this.activePanel = index

    // Focus clicked field
    this.$nextTick(() => {
      this.$refs[`field${index}`][0].focus()
    })
  }
}
```